# "Go by this side" vs. "go from this side"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> 1. He always goes **by** this side.
> 2. He always goes **from** this side.

Comment: It would be nice if you could expound on why you think either of them is or isn't grammatical, and include the results of any research you have done up to this point so we don't duplicate your effort.

Comment: Without context it is impossible to tell which of these equally grammatical sentences has the meaning you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but I am not sure if they would be idiomatic in the context that you have in mind. *By* means *alongside; past or in front of*.

> A house by the lake.
>
> Go by the tall building and turn left.
>
> "The Gulf Stream goes by this side of the cape."

*From* in this context indicates a starting point. In your example it means the person goes *from* this side to...

> The smell is coming from that direction.
>
> Look, the lion is coming from that side of the jungle.